# not show image after use meson and install Elementary OS App

Tags: appimage

I have done my first application in the center of the window I have an image.

image = new Image ();
image.set_from_file("../data/pw.png");

that work well but after compiling and install with these commands:

meson build --prefix=/usr

cd build

ninja

ninja install

the application installs but does not show the image

[image]
[image]

I really appreciate any help, thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by copying the image to `/usr/share/data`. From here, the application can load the image with the following configuration in `meson.build`:

```
# Install our pw.png file so App will see it
install_data(
    'data' / 'pw.png',
    install_dir: get_option('datadir') / 'data',
    rename:'pw.png'
)
```